# Dynamic graph using matplotlib getting slower after a while

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to make a dynamic grid using matplotlib. However, after running for only around 10 interations, the time step seems to be getting longer and longer even though I have set it to a fixed number (0.1 sec in the code). It gets unacceptably slow (around 3 seconds per change) after about 70 iterations. Here's an example of the code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import colors
    import numpy as np


    map=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

    plt.ion()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, tight_layout=True)
    color = ['white', 'black', 'red']
    my_cmap = colors.ListedColormap(color)
    # draw the grid
    for x in range(len(map)):
            ax.axhline(x, lw=2, color='k')
        ax.axvline(x, lw=2, color='k')
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.draw()

    for i in range(0,100):
        x = np.random.randint(0,3)
        y = np.random.randint(0,3)

        map[x][y]+=1
        map[x][y]*=-1
        # draw the boxes
        ax.imshow(map, interpolation='none', cmap=my_cmap, extent=[0, len(map), 0, len(map)])
        # turn off the axis labels
        plt.pause(0.1)
```

I am using python3.7. Is there somewhere wrong with how I draw the graph? Or is there a better way to draw it so that the changing does not slow down after some iterations? Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, you don't delete artists from the previous iterations.

Comment: @gmds what do you mean by "artists"?

Comment: An artist is an object that tells `matplotlib` what to draw. Lines, dots, patches, etc. are all artists. See [this](https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html) for more information. In other words, you continue adding drawing information to your figure, but never remove it even when it's not necessary (hidden by artists in "front") any more.

Comment: @gmds Oh thanks and yes that's exactly I was thinking! I feel like I'm piling up something but i don't know what. Is there any way I can remove the artist or simply update it? I tried moving `ax.imshow()` out of the loop but that way I won't be able to see the graph

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28699792/10694594) which basically does exactly the same.

Instead of calling `imshow` repeatedly, it is more efficient to update the data within the plot.
I would add a variable (`img` below) to store a reference to the displayed image and use `set_data` to change the pixels:

```
img = None
for i in range(0,100):
    x = np.random.randint(0,3)
    y = np.random.randint(0,3)

    map[x][y]+=1
    map[x][y]*=-1

    # draw the boxes
    if img is None:
        img = ax.imshow(map, interpolation='none', cmap=my_cmap, 
                        extent=[0, len(map), 0, len(map)])
    else:
        img.set_data(map)
    # turn off the axis labels
    plt.pause(0.1)
```