# Why does this matlibplot gets slower and slower as I draw updates on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a chart, and want to update it every 0.1 seconds. It seems to work, but right away after 100 updates or so it starts to get very sluggish and update very slowly, even though the data being plotted is the same.

Here is a code that illustrates the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

plt.style.use('dark_background')

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

plt.ion()
plt.show()

i = 5
for row in x:
    axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
    axs[0, 0].set_title("main")

    axs[1, 0].plot(x, y ** 2)
    axs[1, 0].set_title(f"shares {i} with main")
    axs[1, 0].sharex(axs[0, 0])

    axs[0, 1].plot(x + 1, y + 1)
    axs[0, 1].set_title("unrelated")

    axs[1, 1].plot(x + 2, y + 2)
    axs[1, 1].set_title("also unrelated")

    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

    if i == 0:
        fig.tight_layout()

    i += 1

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I suspect I am not clearing something and every time I plot its just adding to it, but I don't really know how to fix it. Some research did not turn up anything useful for this issue.

How can I maintain a constant drawing speed on these updates?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of calling `plot` each time, do `l, = ax.plot(x, y)` the first time, and subsequently `l.set_data((xnew, ynew))`: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_data

Comment: While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692246/matplotlib-draw-is-slow-in-loop-when-it-showing-an-image) is about images, the explanation for _why_ it's happening is the same. The suggestion by Jody should work. You can also move 3 out of the 4 titles out of the loop too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe use `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()`, which improves updating plots significantly. Also `TimedAnimation()` is available, where you can set a specific interval.